# Create and save Make Table Query in VBA

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I am not able to create and save a `make table`-query through VBA. I am able to execute it using (DAO.Database) currentdb.execute, but not save it as a query like I can with a `select query` using `CreateQueryDef`. I want it to be saved as shown on the screenshow below.
Can/Should I use the `.CreateTableDef`? If yes, can you provide an example.

[image] <-- What I want to do

[image] <-- What I can do using `CreateQueryDef`

```
strSQL = "SELECT PRODUCT.product_id, PRODUCT.upc, PRODUCT.name, PRODUCT.size, PRODUCT.uom, PRODUCT.manufacturer, PRODUCT.category, PRODUCT.colour INTO PRODUCT IN 'C:\LIVE IMAGES\" & frm.cboManu.Value & ".mdb'" & _
         " FROM PRODUCT " & _
         "WHERE (((PRODUCT.desc_a) IN (SELECT desc_a FROM PRODUCT WHERE manufacturer LIKE " & Chr(34) & "*" & frm.cboManu.Value & "*" & Chr(34) & ")));"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a QueryDef in order to do this.  Use the Access help on QueryDef.  Hope this helps.

```
    Dim q as QueryDef    
    Set q = New QueryDef
    q.SQL = strSQL
    q.Name = "TEST_SQL"
    CurrentDb.QueryDefs.Append q
    CurrentDb.QueryDefs.Refresh
```